# Glassfih + WSO2 ESB 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: glassfish, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

I am creating "Pass Through Proxy" in WSO2ESB using JAX-WS hosted on Glassfish.

The problem is that the proxy does not work and it happens with **EVERY PROXY** I create in the ESB that are pointing to every **Java Web Services on  Glassfish**: the console gives this error [1]. The thing is that Proxies to .Net Services instead, works fine.

1) I have tried with the **ESB tryit tool** to consume the service and I have the following response:

```
<TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type</TryitProxyError>
```

2) Instead **soapUI** which gives me this message:

```
Error loading [ClientProxy?xsd=http://192.168.10.176:8080/ESBAdminWebapp_SERVER/ClientProxy?xsd=1]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream
```

where `192.168.10.176:8080`is the Glassfish server. But if I call the real WSDL it works...

I have tried with a fresh installation of WSO2-ESB and fresh Glassfish server as well:

WSO2 ESB, Glassfish and IIS are now installed LOCALLY to try to spot the problem.

Please help!

[1] FULL LOG:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-09-24 11:31:11,689] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /services/test.testHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: http://my/Hello/helloRequest, SOAPAction: http://my/Hello/helloRequest, MessageID: urn:uuid:754dfcb5-1008-47ed-9c25-15327370ee11, Direction: request, Envelope: ? {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator 
[2012-09-24 11:31:11,689]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/test.testHttpSoap12E
ndpoint, WSAction: http://my/Hello/helloRequest, SOAPAction: http://my/Hello/hel
loRequest, MessageID: urn:uuid:754dfcb5-1008-47ed-9c25-15327370ee11, Direction:
request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns
:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><p:hello xmlns:
p="http://my/"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><name>?</name></p:hello></soapenv:Body></
soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-09-24 11:31:11,694]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addr
essing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:e9b224e8-2754-41
1f-8640-5922f1797202, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encodin
g='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envel
ope"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns7:binary xmlns:axis2ns7="http://ws.apache.org/commons
/ns/payload"></axis2ns7:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-09-24 11:31:11,697]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http:/
/localhost:8280/services/test.testHttpSoap12Endpoint]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.
java:308)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.jav
a:194)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessa
geWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:449)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(Com
monsHTTPTransportSender.java:276)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisO
peration.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(Out
InAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
165)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:
555)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:
531)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jsp
Service(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:272)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:332)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
14)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleR
equest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonS
tuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcesso
r.java:396)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.pr
ocess(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1534)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that Glassfish response with the following HTTP error:

```
415 Error: Unsupported Media Type
```

This likely means that the `Content-Type` header send by the proxy has a value that is not expected by Glassfish.

Comment: So what do you suggest? P.S. The same configuration was working on a LOCAL deployment.

Comment: Try to intercept the request sent from ESB to Glassfish to determine what the Content-Type is.

Comment: could you point me a method to intercept the request? Also please have a look again at my question since I have edited it. I hope it is clearer now what I am doing.

Comment: This question has probably already been answered on StackOverflow. You need to search a little bit.