# wso2 esb Unsupported Media Type

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I would like my company to use the Wso2ESB, but I have only two days left to convince them, and the creation of Proxy does not work!

I am desperate for a real help for my problem: every proxy that I create seem to produce

```
HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to...
```

(why it is unable to send it?)

```
Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type
```

(is it a consequence of the fact that it could not send? or a problem in the configuration?)

My fresh installation of WSO2 ESB 4.5 is not working with any web service I have tried: JAXWS and C#. I always have the following message LOG:

```
[2012-05-09 08:42:19,381]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/NET.NETHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: http://tempuri.org/Iuser/CheckUserExistsSimple, SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Iuser/CheckUserExistsSimple, MessageID: urn:uuid:6e46c985-3646-4441-ba8d-0c366c063c4b, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><p:CheckUserExistsSimple xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><p:User>-</p:User></p:CheckUserExistsSimple></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2012-05-09 08:42:19,437]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://192.168.10.177:8280/services/NET.NETHttpSoap12Endpoint]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:308)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:450)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:277)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:272)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Unsupported Media Type[2012-05-09 08:44:32,644]  WARN - ClientHandler I/O error : Connection reset by peer For : 192.168.10.71:80
```

Here is the proxy definition:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="NET" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="useOriginalwsdl" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="omitted"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="omitted?wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

when I try to use soapUI to call the proxy service I get this message:

`Error loading [NET?xsd=...?xsd=xsd0]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed` stream

but if I call the real service directly on Glassfish/IIS, it works.

Comment: Are you using soap 12 endpoint ? can you change it to soap 11 and see if the error is there?

Comment: @nuvio: Posting the same question multiple times (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529757/glassfih-wso2-esb-415-unsupported-media-type) doesn't increase the probability of getting an answer.

Comment: @Andreas Veithen you have not been helpful at all so far, fonrtunately there is good people that helped me. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are sending an unsupported message type in your request and it is incompatible with whatever the ESB's message type..

Can you place the TCPmon between your client and ESB and capture the whole message and check what you are actually sending to ESB?

And does your wsdl imports any schemas?..You should provide all schemas if you use publish wsdl option..

First better dont use the publish wsld, option and first try to send message to proxy and see the service is receiving or not

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do what you said.

Comment: How do I provide the schemas? Have to be in a specific ESB folder?

Comment: It worked without publishing WSDL + using the property useOriginalwsdl=true and calling the HttpSoap11Endpoint. Thank you so much for your patience and knowledge!

Comment: Publish wsdl option is used in the cases, where you may need to hide some backend operations/alter those operations (which are vailable at the actual backend service).So, user can not invoke those operations,since you have edited the wsdl, which is at proxy..If there is no such a need, then you do not need to provide the WSDL.In case,if you provide the wsdl when you create a proxy,you have to upload all the relevant schemas to registry and you need to provide "scemaloaction" and the registry key as for the wsdl resources. You will see that option when you provide the wsdl via the proxy wizard.

Comment: If I try to consume the Proxy in Visual Studio or Netbeans, the only method I can see is mediate ( ). Do you know how can I interact with it? For example I would like to call the operation "HelloYou(String your name)" but method "mediate()" does not allow me to do it.

Comment: In this case you have to get the actual backend service's wsdl and create the response(as i said earlier you can use SOPAUI to construct the request payload) eg: after creating soapui project with the service's wsdl(please note that you should not get Proxy's wsdl..where you will see only one default operation call "mediate") you will see a request fromulated for the particular operation(ie:HelloYou) send taht request payload with the parameter to the proxy